# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, .net

I have a .Net application and I am using jQuery and Javascript. I just wanted to load the Bootstrap and jQuery files in a layout page but it is giving the below error. Please help me.

> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEwAC.png)

Comment: can you show how you import this files in html

Comment: How about showing us your project structure?

Comment: The problem seems pretty straightforward, the paths to those files are incorrect, assuming they exist at all.

Comment: importing files like this:<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Answer (score 0):

I think your static path is error. u should fix your static path.

Comment: how you can give static path.